# Android fragment animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, fragment

I have Fragment A and Fragment B. A is added and showing. I want to add B to transaction with custom animation. When B enters from right, A must exit to left and they must do it together at the same time and same speed. How can i achive this?

Example image: [Here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fS9q-7IO-Uc/UIkzWvgeSoI/AAAAAAAAFl8/GESmB7vau7c/s1600/page_margin.png)  (Image showing as ViewPager used, but i cant use ViewPager)

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

First define the animations you want, in res/anim like this

left_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

left_in.xml will be the same, except with a + toXDelta

right_in.xml

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

And then, on `onAttach` of the fragment A to 'left-out'

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

and for fragment B, use

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two animations - Fragment A will use `exit_left.xml` for its **EXIT** animation, and Fragment B will use `enter_right.xml` for its **ENTER** animation.

First, when we attach FragmentA to the activity, we set its EXIT animation:

```
FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();

getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_a_enter, R.anim.exit_left)
            .add(R.id.container, fragmentA, FRAGMENT_A_TAG)
            .commit();
```

Then, we want to replace FragmentA with FragmentB. So we need to set the ENTER animation for FragmentB.

```
FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();

getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_right, R.anim.fragment_b_exit)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragmentB, FRAGMENT_B_TAG)
            .commit();
```

NOTE: `setCustomAnimations` also accepts two optional parameters **popEnter** and **popExit**, which will animate fragment changes when the back button is pressed. If you want that, you need to add `addToBackStack()` to the method chain.

Place the follow animation files in the `res/anim` directory:

`enter_right.xml`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Notice how we are translating the X value from 100% (all the way to the right), to 0%. This will slide in **FragmentB** from right to left.

Finally, we need a `exit_left` animation for **FragmentA** exit to left. We will move this view from 0% to -100%.

`exit_left.xml`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Hope this helps! You can learn more about `FragmentTransaction` and `setCustomAnimations` method here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, i'll try this. But, i need to use .add() not .replace()
Can i do this with add() method?

Comment: Because ı don't want to refresh fragment when onBackPress clicked.